# Stopping/Moving a Robot During Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using ROS Navigation Stack on my robot. How can I get the robot to stop during navigation for example because of safety issues and after the safety issue was resolved the robot moves again towards the goal.

So basically I don't want to cancel the goal as mentioned in [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/46214/move_base-stop-navigation/)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193998/stopping/moving-a-robot-during-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current ROS **Navigation Stack does not offer** a *"pause navigation"* method. Your **best shot** would be to implement a node that **keeps track of the current goal** and when a safety issue occurs, use the [actionlib API](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API) to **cancel the current goal** (and therefore stop the robot) and when the safety issue is solved, **send the goal again**(so the robot moves again).

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-10-02**:
I believe this is correct, but if it seems useful, you should open an issue in the nav repo.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-10-03**:
Thanks for your input @David Lu, I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/259 let's discuss about it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the actionlib to cancel the goal, but I found this method very unreactive. At the moment, if I have to stop my robot, I use its current position as new goal and this is more reactive.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [james P M](https://answers.ros.org/users/56428/james-p-m/) on 2020-08-25**:
how did you do it can you share any file